# Play 2.3.8 logs many netty exceptions but keeps working fine

Tags: playframework, netty

According to [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2766) the following error should be a *non-error* and logged at `TRACE` level:

```
2015-11-15 21:09:12 +0100 - [ERROR] - from play.nettyException in New I/O worker #9 
Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: <U+FFC0>+<U+FFC0>/^@ﾞￌ^Tￌ^Sￌ^U<U+FFC0>
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:102) ~[io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554) ~[io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.closeRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:334) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:260) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.handleDownstream(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:106) [com.typesafe.netty.netty-http-pipelining-1.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812) [io.netty.netty-3.9.3.Final.jar:na]
```

... but as you can see in my case it is logged at `ERROR` level. Is there any workaround to avoid this? I'm using Play 2.3.8.